# Limits in an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $X$ be a real or complex inner product space, and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence in $X$ with $a\in X$.
I want to prove the following:

> 1. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n,b)=(a,b)$ for all $b\in X$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||a_n||=||a||\implies\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$
> 2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a\iff\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n,b)=(a,b)$ uniformly on the unit sphere $\{b\in X:||b||=1\}$.

What I know:
**1** I thought $\left\| a - a_n \right\|^2 = (a-a_n,a-a_n) = \left\| a \right\|^2 + \left\| a_n \right\|^2 - 2 (a_n ,a) \to 2\left\| a \right\|^2 - 2 \left\| a \right\|^2 = 0,$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. Is this correct?

**2** I have no idea where to start this. Any hint to start me off would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1) is correct. For (2), just use Cauchy-Schwartz on the difference of the two terms.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I dont understand your comment on (2), could you maybe explain it further?

Comment: $|(a_n,b)-(a,b)|=|(a_n-a,b)|\le \|a_n-a\|.$

Comment: @mfl But how does this prove the statement?

Comment: $\lVert x\rVert = \sup \{ \lvert \langle x,b\rangle\rvert : \lVert b\rVert = 1\}$

Comment: @DanielFischer I dont see where to use that

Comment: You want to show that $\lVert a_n - a\rVert \to 0$. Look at your premises and my comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please see if I understood your comment correctly? Also why does the equality $||x||=\sup_{b\in X}\{|(x,b)|:||b||=1\}$ hold?

Comment: @mfl Coul you please see if I understood your comment correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's right. In the "$\Rightarrow$" part, you should mention that $b$ belongs to the unit sphere for completeness. It's not strictly necessary to do that, since it is implied by the context, but mentioning it spares the reader the effort to look it up in the context. Regarding $\lVert x\rVert = \sup \{\lvert\langle x,b\rangle\rvert : \lVert b\rVert = 1\}$, the inequality $\leqslant$ follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and then you get the equality a) trivially for $x = 0$ and b) by setting $b = \lVert x\rVert^{-1}\cdot x$ for $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\Rightarrow$ part:
We have $|(a_n,b)-(a,b)|=|(a_n-a,b)|$. The Cauchy Schwarz inequality gives us
$$|(a_n-a,b)|\leq ||a_n-a||\cdot||b||=||a_n-a||\rightarrow0$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

For the $\Leftarrow$ part:
We have
$$||a_n-a||=\sup_{b\in X}\{|(a_n-a,b)|:||b||=1\}=\sup_{b\in X}\{|(a_n,b)-(a,b)|:||b||=1\}\rightarrow0$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.